# Springfox 3.0 Switch to old Display URL back to swagger-ui.html

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox, springfox-boot-starter

My team recently Migrated to Springfox 3.0, looks nice, works well but the change in Display URL `swagger-ui.html` to `swagger-ui/index.html` is a little annoying. I am having trouble finding a way to switch this back without switching to 2.9 or older release. Is anyone able to provide a solution?

Comment: I tried this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/68883020/14252219, and it worked for me